# check euclidean distance across periodic boundaries

Tags: python, math, geometry

What's the best way to check for the euclidean distance between two points when the boundary conditions are periodic? I've tried taking the minimum of the distance and (range - distance) but I think due to the way I've structured the program this is giving weird output. I'm hoping there's another good way to approach this that I can adopt rather than reevaluating the rest of the function.

This is in Python btw. Currently finding euclidean distance with numpy.linalg.norm, though there are SciPy pdist routines that do the same thing that I might use I guess.

Comment: How many dimensions? In what way is the output "weird"?

Comment: Also, you should get into the habit of marking answers as "accepted" when they answer your question satisfactorily; click the tick icon to the left of an answer to accept it.

Comment: "I've tried... but I think due to the way I've structured the program this is giving weird output." Show how you tried; show the expected vs. actual output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should check separately on each dimension for what is smaller between dx and range-dx.

```
def distance(p1, p2):
    total = 0
    for i, (a, b) in enumerate(zip(p1, p2)):
        delta = abs(b - a)
        if delta > dimension[i] - delta:
            delta = dimension[i] - delta
        total += delta ** 2
    return total ** 0.5
```

Comment: this will fail if the points are more than one box length away from each other.

Comment: @dbw: The statement is about two points being inside a n-dimensional box in which you want to consider the space to be an n-dimensional torus; they cannot be more distant than the side of the box.

Comment: True, if you can guarantee that the calling code will always provide coordinates of two points within the same box, no modulus is required.